# Matching query param in vue routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Is there any way to route by a query param? I would like to match the following route: `site.com/?foo=123`. I've tried things like

```
{ path: '/\?foo=[\d]*' }
```

without success.

Comment: You can pass a `query` object when calling `$router.push`. Is that what you mean? Or can you describe the expected behavior and what's not working more clearly?

Comment: @thanksd No that is not what I mean. I want to match a route based on a query string parameter, as opposed to a "regular" id like `/:id`, I need something like `/\?id=[\d]*` to match `/?id=123`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't match a query param in the `path` string of a route definition.

Vue Router uses `path-to-regexp`, and [its documentation](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) says:

> The RegExp returned by path-to-regexp is intended for use with pathnames or hostnames. It can not handle the query strings or fragments of a URL.

---

You *can* use regular expressions to match on a route param by specifying the regex in parenthesis after the param name like so:

```
{ path: '/:foo([\d]*)' },
```

But, Vue Router's route params can't be in the query.

[Here are some examples of the different route-matching features Vue Router provides.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-matching/app.js)

---

If you really need to check the query of the url, you could use the `beforeEnter` handler to match the query manually and then reroute if it isn't the correct format:

```
const routes = [{
  name: 'home',
  path: '/',
  component: Home,
  beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
    if (to.query.foo && to.query.foo.match(/[\d]*/)) {
      next({ name: 'foo', query: to.query });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
}, {
  name: 'foo',
  path: '/',
  component: Foo,
}];
```

Comment: The regular expression "parenthesis after the param name" example you give will make the router use that route for the root to. Super close to working though!