# Vue How to match a query route

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In my `vuejs`-application I have a route that looks like this:

```
myapp.com/pages/verify?query=something123
```

but in my `router.js` I cannot figure out to match this route, so I can render a specific view. So I thought maybe something like this?:

```
path: "/pages/verify/:query"
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matching query param in vue routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797824/matching-query-param-in-vue-routes)

Comment: In this example, you're setting a route pattern for `/pages/verify/<anything>`, where the value of <anything> is set to the variable called `query`.

Comment: don't forget to mark an answer if it helped!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a parameter from the URL you cannot do it using the router.

The path in your router should be simply `/pages/verify` then in your component you can get the URL parameters using the `$route` object.

For example if your URL is `http://myapp.com/pages/verify?query=something123&param2=abc` then you can get those parameter (within a component) as per below:

- `this.$route.query.query`
- `this.$route.query.param2`

VUE documentation: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to get the query param passed into your component as a prop: set a function for the props object for that route definition. You can read more about "function mode" [on the docs website](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode).

```
[
    {
        path: '/pages/verify',
        name: 'verify',
        component: MyVerifyPageComponent,
        props: route => ({
            query: route.query,
        }),
    },
]
```

I should note, however, that since the `query` object is a map of every query key-value pair, if you use `?query=sometext`, you would need to access it by `route.query.query`.

In your original example, however, you're setting a dynamic route path, (like a wildcard), that would match things like `myapp.com/pages/verify/pageid-123` and even `myapp.com/pages/verify/the/entire/string/past/verify`. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching